# How to dynamically use getters/setters in Dart

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

```
class User{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
}
```

I want to be able to get and set one of the fields in user with a dynamically selected symbol or string. For example `String value = u[new Symbol("firstName")];`

I see that InstanceMirror has a getField method, but it doesn't seem to return the value. All I need is the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a symbol with # you need to know the name at compile time.
I got it working this way:

```dart
library operator_lib;

import 'dart:mirrors';

void main(List<String> args) {
  var x = new X();
  var f = new Symbol('firstName');
  var r = reflect(x);
  print(r.getField(f).reflectee);
  r.setField(f, "John");
  print(r.getField(f).reflectee);

}

class X {
  String firstName = 'Mike';
}
```